# Bounding the uncertainty function in Robust Inverse Dynamic Control

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems, control-theory, robotics

Given the standard dynamical model of an n-DOF robotic system consists of only revolute joints:

$ M(q)\ddot{q} + C(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+g(q)=\tau $

The robust inverse dynamics control input $\tau$ can be written as

$\tau = \hat{M}(q) u + \hat{C}(q,\dot{q})\dot{q}+\hat{g}(q)$

where the notation $\hat{(\cdot)}$ represents an estimate of the theoretically accurate value, and the error is written as $\tilde{(\cdot)}=\hat{(\cdot)}-(\cdot)$.

If the outer-loop control input is chosen as:

$u=\ddot{q}_d+K_d \dot{\tilde{q}}+K_p \tilde{q}+\delta\;$ where $\delta$ is a term to-be-designed.

then the closed-loop system can be obtained as:

$\ddot{q}=u+\underbrace{M^{-1}\tilde{M}u+M^{-1}(\tilde{C}\dot{q}+\tilde{g})}_{:= \eta(q,\,\dot{q},u)}$

or in state-space representation as,

$e=\begin{bmatrix}
e_1 \\
e_2
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\tilde{q}\\
\dot{\tilde{q}}
\end{bmatrix}, \; \dot{e}=\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0 & I \\
-K_p & - K_d
\end{bmatrix}}_{:=A}e+\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
-I
\end{bmatrix}}_{:=B}[\delta+\eta]$

Define $E:=M^{-1}\tilde{M}$, then the uncertainty function $\eta$ can be expressed as,

$\eta =E \, \delta + E(\ddot{q}_d +K_d \dot{\tilde{q}}+K_p \tilde{q})+M^{-1}(\tilde{C}\dot{q}+\tilde{g})$

Then, according to the textbook *Robot Modeling and Control* (Spong & Vidyasagar), for some $\alpha < 1$, $\gamma_1$, $\gamma_2$, and $\gamma_3 (t)$, the uncertainty function can be thus bounded:

$||\eta|| \leq \alpha ||\delta || + \gamma_1 ||e || + \gamma_2 ||e||^2 + \gamma_3 (t)$

But I am really struggling to see where this inequality comes from. I understand how the first term $\alpha ||\delta||$ is designed since $||M^{-1}||$ is bounded, and the second term involving $||e||$ also seems reasonable as we have joint variables in $\eta$. But I couldn't get the idea behind the terms $\gamma_2 ||e||^2$ and $\gamma_3 (t)$.

Comment: Isn't it explained in the textbook where this bound comes from ??

Comment: As far as I know, the textbook just stated that $\eta$ can be thus bounded but did not explain this inequality.